# Filter data using nodejs and elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch

I'm currently facing an issue with my datatable implemented in ReactJS. I'm retrieving data from elasticsearch and populating the datatable with it. The data retrieval process works fine without the filter applied, however, when I apply filters to the data, the datatable remains empty, even though the data _source has matching records.

**The structure of the parameters I am sending is as follows:**

```
{
  pageIndex: 1,
  pageSize: 10,
  sort: { order: '', key: '' },
  query: '',
  filterData: {
    analysis: [ '0', '1', '2', '3' ],
    threat_level_id: [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ],
  }
}
```

**EndPoint:**

> POST /api/v1/events/public/list

**Controller:**

```
exports.getPublicEvents = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    client.ping()
    const { pageIndex, pageSize, sort, query, filterData } = req.body
    let esQuery = {
      index: 'ns_*',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match_all: {},
              },
            ],
            filter: [],
          },
        },
        from: (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize,
        size: pageSize,
      },
    }
    if (query) {
      esQuery.body.query.bool.must = [
        {
          match: {
            'Event.info': {
              query: query,
              fuzziness: 'AUTO',
            },
          },
        },
      ]
    }
    if (filterData.analysis.length > 0) {
      esQuery.body.query.bool.filter.push({
        terms: {
          'Event.analysis': filterData.analysis,
        },
      })
    }
    if (filterData.threat_level_id.length > 0) {
      esQuery.body.query.bool.filter.push({
        terms: {
          'Event.threat_level_id': filterData.threat_level_id,
        },
      })
    }
    let esResponse = await client.search(esQuery)
    let data = esResponse.hits.hits.map((hit) => hit._source)
    let total = esResponse.hits.total.value

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      total: total,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Error connecting to Elasticsearch',
      errorMessage: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

The controller below is without filters and it works just fine.

```
exports.getPublicEvents = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    client.ping()
    const { pageIndex, pageSize, sort, query } = req.body
    let esQuery = {
      index: 'ns_*',
      body: {
        query: {
          match_all: {},
        },
        from: (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize,
        size: pageSize,
      },
    }
    if (query) {
      esQuery.body.query = {
        match: {
          'Event.info': {
            query: query,
            fuzziness: 'AUTO',
          },
        },
      }
    }
    let esResponse = await client.search(esQuery)
    let data = esResponse.hits.hits.map((hit) => hit._source)
    let total = esResponse.hits.total.value

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: data,
      total: total,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: 'Error connecting to Elasticsearch',
      errorMessage: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

**ElasticSearech version: 7.17.8**

**Result of: console.log(JSON.stringify(esQuery))**

```
{
  "index": "INDEX_NAME",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [{ "match_all": {} }],
        "filter": [
          { "terms": { "Event.analysis": ["0", "1", "2"] } },
          { "terms": { "Event.threat_level_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4"] } }
        ]
      }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
  }
}
```

**Data in elascticsearch schema**

```
{
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2023-02-01T14:43:09.997Z",
    "Event": {
        "info": ".......................",
        
        "description": ".......................",
        "analysis": 0,
        "threat_level_id": "4",
        "created_at": 1516566351,
        "uuid": "5a64f74f0e543738c12bc973322",
        "updated_at": 1675262417
    }
}
```

**Index Mapping**

```
{
    "index_patterns": ["INDEX_NAME"],
    "template": "TEMPLATE_NAME",
    "settings": {
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "index.mapping.nested_objects.limit": 10000000
      },
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "Event": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "date_occured": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "threat_level_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "description": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "is_shared": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "analysis": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "uuid": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "created_at": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "info": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "shared_with": {
                "type": "nested",
                 "properties": {
                  "_id": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "updated_at": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "author": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "Attributes": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "type": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "comment": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "category": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "value": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "timestamp": {
                  "type": "date"
                }
              }
            }, 
            "organisation": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "uuid": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "Tags": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "color": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "TLP": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "color": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }  
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are some values you are sending in `query` in your controller ? is it the first snippet ?
Do you not have errors from `es client` ? Logs we could analyze ?

Comment: The params Im sending are mensionned in my question and the data returned is empty and get no errors in es client

Comment: Can you print out the query that is generated when you apply filters? like `JSON.stringify(esQuery)`. Also can you specify which version of the ES client you're using because in recent versions, the `body` parameter disappeared and the `query` should be specified at the top-level?

Comment: I updated my question and added the ES version and JSON.stringify(esQuery) result

Comment: @Val i also added the schema of the data in ES

Comment: I can see that your docs have `Event.threat_level` but your query has `Event. threat_level_id `

Comment: @Val never mind that i just changed the property name

Comment: side note: size/from go outside of the body section, which should only contains the query part

Comment: @Val The controller  without filters works just fine using from & size inside the body !

Comment: Just saying that it [doesn't adhere to the contract](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/7.17/api-reference.html#_search), it might work but they might not be taken into account. Anyway, it's not the issue. How many hits do you get when performing this query directly in Kibana Dev Tools?

Comment: And it still concerns me that you had `threat_level` vs `threat_level_id` if you copy/pasted your document directly into SO

Comment: @Val It was just a typo and I updated it in the question. its threat_level_id

Comment: @Val did you find anything that can help me solve this issue sir?

Comment: You did not answer my last question: How many hits do you get when performing this query directly in Kibana Dev Tools **on the same index**?

Comment: @Val I get empty hits:

"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }

Comment: When I remove the filter part the query works just fine.

"filter": [
          { "terms": { "Event.analysis": ["0", "1", "2"] } },
          { "terms": { "Event.threat_level_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4"] } }
        ]

Comment: Can you share your index mapping in your question?

Comment: @Val I updated my question and added the index mapping

Comment: Thanks, but note that I still see a field called `threat_level` and not `threat_level_id` in your mapping. Added my answer though

Comment: Don't worry about it because I updated threat_level_id to threat_level in my real mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Event` is a nested field, so you need to use nested queries, like this:

```
{
  "index": "INDEX_NAME",
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [{ "match_all": {} }],
        "filter": [
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "Event",
              "query": {"terms": { "Event.analysis": ["0", "1", "2"] }}
            } 
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "Event",
              "query": {"terms": { "Event.threat_level_id": ["1", "2", "3", "4"] }}
            } 
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr @Val  for your help. It's working now :)